# how to call a function on press of a action button in push notification react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

i am able to generate notification along with action buttons but how to call a onpress event based on the button pressed by user? here yes or no
thanks in advance

> import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';
>
> ```
> function configure() {
>   PushNotification.configure({
>     // (required) Called when a remote is received or opened, or local notification is opened
>     onNotification: function (notification) {
>       console.log('NOTIFICATION:', notification);
>       // process the notification
>       // (required) Called when a remote is received or opened, or local notification is opened
>       notification.finish();
>     },
>     // IOS ONLY (optional): default: all - Permissions to register.
>     permissions: {
>       alert: true,
>       badge: true,
>       sound: true,
>     },
>     // Should the initial notification be popped automatically
>     // default: true
>     popInitialNotification: true,
>     /**
>      * (optional) default: true
>      * - Specified if permissions (ios) and token (android and ios) will requested or not,
>      * - if not, you must call PushNotificationsHandler.requestPermissions() later
>      * - if you are not using remote notification or do not have Firebase installed, use this:
>      *     requestPermissions: Platform.OS === 'ios'
>      */
>     requestPermissions: true,
>     requestPermissions: Platform.OS === 'ios',
>     'content-available': 1,
>   });
> }
>
>
> function givenotification(title, message) {
>   PushNotification.localNotification({
>     channelId: 'channel',
>     message: message, // (required)
>     title: title,
>     message: message, // (required) 
>   actions: ["Yes", "No"]
>   });
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I have never used push notification directly,
for my notification i have use [React Native Notifee](https://notifee.app/) that have this "displayNotification" inside when you try to log Notifee ..
I suggest you to try log "PushNotification" to find a function to display your notification.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup the action as below code:

```
export const App = () => {
  const [permissions, setPermissions] = useState({});

  /**
   * By calling this function, a notification with category `userAction` will have action buttons
   */
  const setNotificationCategories = () => {
    PushNotificationIOS.setNotificationCategories([
      {
        id: 'userAction',
        actions: [
          {id: 'open', title: 'Open', options: {foreground: true}},
          {
            id: 'ignore',
            title: 'Desruptive',
            options: {foreground: true, destructive: true},
          },
          {
            id: 'text',
            title: 'Text Input',
            options: {foreground: true},
            textInput: {buttonTitle: 'Send'},
          },
        ],
      },
    ]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    PushNotificationIOS.addEventListener('notification', onRemoteNotification);
  });

  const onRemoteNotification = (notification) => {
    const actionIdentifier = notification.getActionIdentifier();

    if (actionIdentifier === 'open') {
      // Perform action based on open action
    }

    if (actionIdentifier === 'text') {
      // Text that of user input.
      const userText = notification.getUserText();
      // Perform action based on textinput action
    }
  };
};
```

For more, you can reach out to the official documentation of the library.

https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification